# Can we use MVC 4.0 application to build hybrid app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

My existing code in MVC4.0 , controller classes action are http based. So it is MVC 4.0 and webapi. However we don't have sperare sercices and controller classes are connecting database context to deal with database operation.

Now, we are looking to make this web application as mobile application. The current website support RWD. Can we use MVC4.0 view to build app? or I have to develop service layer and use some JS framework to call it?  I am developing hybrid app using phonegap. We have to leverage existing code.

If we wrap this MVC based code using phonegap will it work in apple appstore and android store

Comment: I come to know that MVC code won't work after wrapping it into hybrid app.... hybrid app is all together different concept.   we can't tied mvc.net and hybrid app

Answer (score 1):

when you develop a hybrid app, you only use HTML, CSS and JavaScript, for your case, you can use the web api controllers like and endpoint and consume it from your hybrid app through ajax.

With hybrid apps, you have great tools and frameworks, one of them is Ionic thats is based on Angularjs (and of course, use apache cordova).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using Xamarin rather than Phonegap. Xamarin has a Razor templating engine that allows you to use .cshtml templates on the client side along with web services. That can result in greater code re-use between your MVC app and your hybrid mobile app. More information here:

[Sharper HTML Hybrid Apps with Razor](https://blog.xamarin.com/sharper-html-hybrid-apps-with-razor/)